# Is there a less convoluted way of writing this in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, dom

I'm creating an array of DOM elements (HTML) without having to look up into the DOM, like so:

```
const frames = [
    ...document.createRange()
        .createContextualFragment(
            new String(
                new Array(options.length)
                    .fill()
                    .map((v, i) => `<div class="page"><iframe src="./renders/page-${i + 1}"></iframe></div>`)
                )
            )
        .querySelectorAll('div')
].map((page, index) => _addPageWrappersAndBaseClasses(page, index))
```

Is there a more sane way of doing this?

Comment: The sanity of the code implementation is not to be judged by anyone else and is off topic for this site.

Comment: I have added a few line breaks to your code to make it at least readable within the question context.  If that was the point of this question, then you can rollback.

Comment: line breaks are fine. I'm looking for an alternate approach, this code is sane and quite clear to me otherwise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, just don't put everything on one line. Instead make sensible use of variables and line breaks.

```
const divStrings = new Array(options.length)
  .fill()
  .map((v, i) =>
    `<div class="page"><iframe src="./renders/page-${i + 1}"></iframe></div>`
  )

const frag = document.createRange().createContextualFragment(new String(foo))

const divs = [...frag.querySelectorAll('div')]

const frames = divs.map(_addPageWrappersAndBaseClasses)
```

Only change to the code above, other than the formatting and variables, is that the anonymous callback to `.map` at the end was extraneous. I changed it to pass the function being called directly.

You could get rid of a variable or two, so it doesn't need to be quite that drawn out, but there's not really any benefit to packing everything into a single expression.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it would be both more efficient and more concise to use regular DOM methods.

```
for(let i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
    const page = document.createElement("div");
    page.className = "page";
    const frame = document.createElement("iframe");
    frame.src = `./renders/page-${i + 1}`;
    page.appendChild(frame);
    _addPageWrappersAndBaseClasses(page, i);
}
```

You should also try to avoid parsing HTML with strings in JavaScript.

Comment: Cool! This is the original way people would have written this, prior to ES6 standard may be. I was looking for an alternate with a more functional approach, i.e. without using `for loops`, but thank you, this would work just fine as well.

Comment: You shouldn't put unnecessary effort into trying not to use `for` loops if they are more concise, especially in this case since parsing HTML with strings is not good practice.